# How to fix Opencv arcLength function error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, opencv

The following code is giving me the following error:

```
contours = cv2.findContours(horizontal_lines_canvas, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[1]
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.arcLength(c, True), reverse=True)[:2]
```

**ERROR:**

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:237: error: (-215:Assertion failed) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'arcLength'

- **OpenCV version:** 4.0.0
- **Python version:** 3.7

Why so ? All seems correct

Comment: It's `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)`, see [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). In your case, `contours` is a tuple, thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, HansHirse.

Replaced with:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(..
```